# Subgroup of the semidirect product of two subgroups with coprime orders

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

It is well known that if $\gcd (|H|,|K|)=1$ then all subgroups
of $H\times K$ are of the form $H^{\prime }\times K^{\prime }$ such that $H^{\prime}$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $K^{\prime}$ is a subgroup of
$K$.why it is not true for the subgroups of the semi-direct product $H\rtimes K$.

Comment: Hint: try with $K$ of order 2 in a particular example: what are the subgroups of order 2?

Comment: It might be more realistic to expect that each subgroup of the semidirect product might be a semidirect product of subgroups $H_{1},K_{1},$ with $H_{1}$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $H$ and $K_{1}$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $K.$ In fact, in your situation, $H_{1}$ can be taken to be a subgroup of $H,$ and you might consider the possible relationship between $K_{1}$ and $K$ .

Comment: The reason it is not true is because there are counterexamples, and in fact the smallest example of a nontrivial semidirect product  with factors of coprime orders provides a counterexample.

Comment: OK thank you very much. But what we can say about this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1330267/550778. Is it false.

Answer (score 2):

As YCor said, something as easy as $S_3=C_3\rtimes C_2$ provides a counter-example. The most important result dealing with the situation you are interested in is the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

Comment: OK thank you very much. But what we can say about this answer math.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330088/subgroups-of-semidirect-product/1330267#1330267. Is it false.

Comment: What we can say is that this answer uses the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem.  Note also that a *conjugate* of the (subgroup of the) acting group is used there.